ILGPU: EnableAlgorithms not supported on RTX 4090?
I have an RTX 4090 with CUDA 12.5 installed on this machine. The graphics drivers are up to date.
The below code is in a NET 8.0 C# VS 2022 project with the ILGPU and ILGPU.Algorithms NuGet packages installed.
The second line throws System.NotSupportedException: 'Not supported target accelerator', and I've verified that my GPU is not listed in the available devices in the context when algorithms are enabled. The accelerator works fine without them.
context = Context.Create(b => b.EnableAlgorithms());
accelerator = context.CreateCudaAccelerator(0);

Unfortunately I need to use Math.Atan2 which is not supported without Algorithms.
Kind of at a loss here.

they have a discord channel

Didn't find this right away, so I'm posting here to help those who Google this and miss.
My GPU goes missing when enabling algorithms #674
context = Context.Create(b => b.Default().EnableAlgorithms());

